# Symfony2 override a form widget in Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to override a form widget in Twig following this documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form

But I'm a little bit lost.
Here is the **select** field I want to breakdown:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.activities) }}
```

Here is the overriding process taken in the doc:

```
    {% form_theme edit_form _self %}

    {%- block choice_widget_options -%}
        {% for group_label, choice in options %}
            {%- if choice is iterable -%}
                <optgroup label="{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? group_label : group_label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}">
                    {% set options = choice %}
                    {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
                </optgroup>
            {%- else -%}
                {% set attr = choice.attr %}
                <option value="{{ choice.value }}" {{ block('attributes') }}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {% endfor %}
    {%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}
```

The purpose is to be able to select multiple field in the select box with an array of ids posted through my controller.

You guys have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Did you try to use the "multiple" option of the choice widget?

Comment: I putted in my FormType: 'multiple' => true. Is it what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with Twig didn't work. So I did it on the FormType side.

The solution: Using a PRE_SET_DATA. I override the form with the **'data'** option.

Here is the code for you:

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var  $em EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * TagType constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Tags',
            ])
            ->add('activities', 'entity', [
                'label'    => 'Affecter à des activitées',
                'mapped'   => false,
                'class'    => 'App\TagBundle\Entity\Activity\Activity',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr'     => [
                    'data-js'          => 'chosen',
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Affecter à des activitées',
                ],
            ]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $tag = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        /** Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection $taggingCollection */
        $taggingCollection = $tag->getTagging();

        if ($taggingCollection == null)
            return; // leave if no tag (probably a new action)

        $activitiesIds = array();
        /** @var \App\TagBundle\Entity\Activity\Tagging $tagging */
        foreach( $taggingCollection as $tagging){
            $activitiesIds[] = $tagging->getResourceId();
        }

        $em = $this->em;
        $activities = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach($activitiesIds as $activityId) {
            $activity = $em->getRepository('AppTagBundle:Activity\Activity')->find($activityId);
            $activities->add($activity);
        }

        $form->add('activities', 'entity', [
            'label'    => 'Editer les activitées affectées',
            'mapped'   => false,
            'class'    => 'App\TagBundle\Entity\Activity\Activity',
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'attr'     => [
                'data-js'          => 'chosen',
                'data-placeholder' => 'Affecter à des activitées',
            ],
            'data' => $activities
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'App\TagBundle\Entity\Activity\Tag',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'App_TagBundle_activity_tag';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Firstly check if path to your template is correct:  app/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig

Next, in the template where you are using the form, you have to specify your customized template to be used

{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}

{{ form_widget(edit_form.activities) }}
```